# Changing the size of a table to use as a diagram

Tags: tables, diagrams

I am producing this table as a diagram, this is what I need it to look like but much bigger. How do I change the size of the table itself? Or is there a better way?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & & & & &\\
                    \hline 
                \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use `tabularx` and choose the size you want.

Comment: How would I do that? I have all the dimensions I want, I just want them to be scaled up so its 3 times the size.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘having all dimensions I want’. Which dimensions? With tabularx you choose the overall width, and it produces equal columns.

Comment: I mean I want a 6x1 table with no entries, like the one I've produced above, however I want its actual size to be bigger so that it fills up more of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `tabularx` and an invisible rule for the height. You can choose the `tabularx` environment width either as a fraction of the line width, or as a given length. I don't know if it has to float nor if it should have a caption, so I decided that it would not, and simply put it in a `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
        \hline
    \rule{0pt}{1cm} & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\lipsum[23]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but the example below covers two possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]\centering  % this is a float, i.e. TeX can move it around
    \huge
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & & & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]


\begin{table}[h]\centering  % this is a float, i.e. TeX can move it around
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
    A   & B & & & &\\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```